# Show only a few packages from a list

Tags: java, android

I want the list to show only a number of apps (packages) that I will define in advance
How can this be done

Thank you

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add((ApplicationInfo) info);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return applist;
    }
    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, applist);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

### adapter

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {

    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;

        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            checkList.add(false);
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        }
        return view;
    }
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: How will you define the pacakges in adavance? By name or something else?

Comment: Using the package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that you have all the package names in a list of String. Then you can do the following:

```
 ArrayList packageList = new ArrayList<String>();// To this list you will add all the package names
 ...
 ...
 ...
  private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (packageList.contains(info.packageName)) {
                applist.add((ApplicationInfo) info);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return applist;
}
```

Comment: It works Thank you very much

Comment: How can I take control of activity name as well?
Because if the app has two activities with a launcher this code does not handle it